# How do I set git fetch --force in git config?

Tags: git, git-config, git-fetch

I want every fetch and pull to get tags from origin, replacing local ones if they differ, and delete tags and `origin/` branches that are not on origin, so I did this:

```
git config --global fetch.tags true
git config --global fetch.force true
git config --global fetch.prune true
git config --global fetch.pruneTags true
```

I still need to type `git fetch --force` to "clobber" existing tags. The rest works fine. How do I properly add the force flag to git config?

This is in my .gitconfig:

```
[fetch]
    tags = true
    force = true
    prune = true
    pruneTags = true
```

Comment: Do you really want your tags to be clobbered? They don’t have a “remote” (local: `refs/remotes`) counterpart.

Comment: You say you set things like `fetch.force`. But are those configs a thing? I can’t find that particular one in `man git config`. I think remote-tracking refs just get *clobbered* by default.

Comment: @Guildenstern Yes, the only reason I would create a local tag is to immediately push it.

Comment: But if you (1) pushed a tag and then (2) someone force-updated it and then (3) you fetched it with clobbering you would end up with their force update and your own tag location would be (eventually) gone.

Comment: @Guildenstern That's fine, I keep my local work on branches. Tags are for releases.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) : `fetch.force` and `fetch.tags` don't exist.

You can set an alias:

```
git config --global alias.fetchp "fetch --prune --prune-tags --force --tags"
```

and use

```
git fetchp
```

Comment: I see, `--tags` is apparently on by default which is why I thought it worked in .gitconfig. This wasn't the case previously as I wouldn't get new tags on commits I'd already fetched. Is there any way to use this alias fetch when pulling in Eclipse?